# How to split month in first 10 days, next 10 days, and remaining days of a month in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

This query is going to group by month and year in SQL. I want a select query for this question where the user will enter `FromDate` and `ToDate`:

The query I am testing:

```
select 
    year(CDate) as Payment_year, 
    count(distinct CDate) as count_days,
    month(CDate) as month_name,
    isnull(sum(Amount),0.00) as Total_Amount 
from 
    tblCowMilk
where 
    CDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31' 
group by 
    year(CDate),
    month(CDate),
    (datepart(day,CDate))/11 
order by 
    month_name
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qygKk.png)

I want a result like this

```
                    Payment Register for the Period: 01-05-2015 to 23-02-2016         
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MONTH      days      I PERIOD    days   II PERIOD   day   III PERIOD      TOTAL  
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
May           10         10.00     10      160.00       11       0.00         170.00

June                     30.00               0.00                0.00          30.00

July                     20.00               0.00               10.00          30.00

August                    0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00

September                10.00               0.00                0.00          10.00

October                   0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00

November                  0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00

December                  0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00

January                   0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00

February                  0.00               0.00                0.00           0.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         70.00             160.00               10.00         240.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Check out PIVOT .. seems to be you just need PIVOT countDays and TotalAmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic calculating the 10-day groups is wrong, currently it's

```
1-10
11-21
22-end of month
```

This should return the correct result:

```
select 
    year(CDate) as Payment_year, 
    count(* as count_days,
    month(CDate) as month_name,
    sum(case when period = 1 then Total_Amount else 0 end) as Period_I,
    sum(case when period = 2 then Total_Amount else 0 end) as Period_II,
    sum(case when period = 3 then Total_Amount else 0 end) as Period_III,
    isnull(sum(Total_Amount),0.00) as Total_Amount
from
 (
   select 
      CDate,
      case -- 10 days within a period
         when datepart(day,CDate) <= 10 then 1
         when datepart(day,CDate) <= 20 then 3
         else 3
      end as period,
     sum(Amount) as Total_Amount
   from 
      tblCowMilk
   where 
      CDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31' 
   group by 
      CDate,
      case
         when datepart(day,CDate) <= 10 then 1
         when datepart(day,CDate) <= 20 then 3
         else 3
      end
 ) as dt
group by year(CDate), month(CDate)
order by year(CDate), month(CDate)
```

To get the Grand Total you need Standard SQL's Extended Grouping, I don't know if SQL Server 2012 fully supports this:

```
group by
   grouping sets ((year(CDate),month(CDate)),())
order by
   grouping(year(CDate)), year(CDate),
   grouping(month(CDate)), month(CDate)
```

Or do the total within you application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    year(a.CDate) as Payment_year, 
    month(a.CDate) as month_name,
    COUNT(b.Amount) as 'I Period',
    COUNT(c.Amount) as 'II Period',
    COUNT(d.Amount) as 'II Period',
    isnull(sum(a.Amount),0.00) as Total_Amount 
from 
    tblCowMilk a 
left join tblCowMilk d on d.CDate = a.CDate and DAY(d.CDate) < 11
left join tblCowMilk b on b.CDate = a.CDate and DAY(b.CDate) >10  and DAY(b.CDate) <21
left join tblCowMilk c on c.CDate = a.CDate  and DAY(c.CDate) >20
where 
    a.CDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31' 

group by 
    year(a.CDate),
    month(a.CDate),
order by 
    month_name
```